# how to animate only one field of a recyclerView item

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which item contains `ImageView1`, `TextView1`, `TextView2`, `ImageView2`. I want that when the app runs, `textView2` to have an animation slideInLeft infinitely, for every item of the `recyclerView` and when you scroll down and come back to an item, the animation to start again.

My `TextView` in xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/slideingText"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:text="this is some other text if you need this to be done you have to do it yourself"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:id="@+id/currentShowTitle"/>
```

In my RecyclerVew Adapter I did something like this:

```
setAnimation(holder.currentShowTitle,position);
```

where

```
 private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
    {
        if (position > lastPosition)
        {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }
```

I also used

```
 @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ChannelsViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
        ((ChannelsViewHolder)holder).clearAnimation();
    }
```

The problem is that when app runs, it animates as I want only the first item and when I scroll down and come back, animation doesn't start again.
Does anybody know how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your method in:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(mAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position)
{
setAnimation(//pass parameters(position etc...));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `OnBindViewHolder` write the following code

```
if (position == 0) {
     holder.yourView.startAnimation(Your_animation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate every time when you scroll. Remove the position check to which you kept to store last position and Here you go :

```
 private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
{

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);

}
```